# How to preserve html comments in Ckeditor when editing an existing document

Tags: ckeditor

How can I make sure that user typed in html comment is visible when editing an older document in Ckeditor? Use case is that users want to discuss about html formatting and they want others to see exactly what they wrote. I tried disabling the ACF by using `config.allowedContent = true;` but that had no effect in this case. Maybe the escaping of the document in html response must done differently? Or am I forced to instruct users to use some special formatting to avoid losing written html tags for later editing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a check for double encoding the message on server side that lead the response be `&lt;p&gt;&lt;!-- This is an example` when it should have been `&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;!-- This is an example` I removed the check and now it works.